# Appropriateness of recent LIGO question for MO

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-topic, scope

There had been numerous comments under the question [Recent observation of gravitational waves](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/231078/recent-observation-of-gravitational-waves) that discuss whether it is appropriate for MathOverflow. That discussion is properly a concern of MO meta, so I am setting up a thread for it here.

The comments at main have now been transferred to http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35708/discussion-on-question-by-richard-stanley-recent-observation-of-gravitational-wa and deleted at main, so people can see the main points of the prior discussion but without cluttering up the MO thread. I respectfully request that further discussion avoid terms like "MO police" or "censorship", etc., which tend to create more heat than light.

Part of the discussion revolves around the fact that the OP has a high reputation both in terms of points and in real life, and this makes a difference in how the question should be treated. This might be worth discussing in a separate meta post.

Anyway, on the table is whether the question is appropriate for MO, and if not, should it be migrated to Physics or Astronomy? (Edit: it seems that migration would likely result in a "closure as duplicate" at either of those sites, so the latter question is probably off the table.)

Comment: Isn't it a no-brainer that high-rep (IRL or virtual) should be completely irrelevant?

Comment: It should be pointed out that the question would likely be closed as duplicate at both Physics and Astronomy (e.g., of http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/235720/how-did-ligo-detect-the-source-of-the-gravitational-waves?rq=1 or http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13725/why-can-we-detect-gravitational-waves). So a possible yardstick would be "What answers could the MO community give that the others couldn't" (and possibly edit the question accordingly).

Comment: @Danu I agree the rep should be irrelevant, but others feel differently. This has been discussed in meta elsewhere, but I'd have to track down where.

Comment: @Danu given that there are explicit assertions to the contrary in comments on the post  'no'. That being said, in this context, I completely agree it should be irrelevant. (There are other situations were there is an argument to be made for considering it, roughly speaking there may be less need for giving explicit context for a post, when there is implicit context by virtue who posted it.)

Comment: @danu  I'd argue that who is asking adds critical context about what level and kind of answer is appropriate.  No answer is appropriate to all audiences.

Comment: @user1504 I'm not very well-acquainted with mathoverflow (I come here mostly to stand in awe at you guys' interesting yet forever-out-of-reach discussions) but as far as "normal" Stack Exchange sites go, it is very important to have answers of *varying* difficulty/depth, regardless of who posted the question. Thus, even in this context, reputation of the asker should be disregarded (again, this may be different here on MO where not everything is necessarily as it is on other SE sites).

Comment: @user1504 this reasoning can be applicable in some contexts in the current case the reasoning felt purely along the lines of giving a "celebrity bonus." This is quite explicit in Lucia's comment. Put differently how specifically would the answers differ were the question asked by some graduate student. How?

Comment: I am willing to let MO rep contribute toward giving a benefit of the doubt. If someone has contributed as much to the site as the OP, then why not give the question a chance?

Comment: Another argument why the question should be improved independently of who asked it: What if Richard Stanley decides to delete his account at some point (as others have done before him), and it becomes user2807's question?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I do not quite understand the notion of giving the benefit of the doubt here. There is no doubt; OP made it quite clear it is an idle curiosity (and this is not meant as a critique rather as a positive). Would OP ask a question in combinatorics that seems questionable to me, then I would agree I should better question my judgment and hold back on taking action (and this may reasonably be different if it were asked by some arbitrary user instead). What seems  the case is simply that a question should get a pass because somebody well-known asked it that would not otherwise.

Comment: Nobody seems to have gotten a ``celebrity bonus" or a "pass".   If five people vote to close, the question still gets closed, and if five vote to reopen then it gets reopened.  There may be many reasonable views on this, but I don't see why they cannot be respected.

Comment: @Lucia because the notion that different users should be treated in fundamentally different ways merely based on on-site or off-site merits without relation to the situation at hand  is highly objectionable and borderline offensive to some, in any case it is to me. Indeed it is sometimes criticized this were the case, usually in the other way round. This attitude also fuels existing negative  preconceptions against this site as being some in-clique (I do not say this is the case but the conception exist).

Comment: That's too bad if you find such a perspective offensive.  Others might find questionable the idea of insisting that no perspective besides one's own can be valid --- you have made numerous comments here about how you think about this issue, but surely there can be other viewpoints?

Comment: Offensive is a completely useless word in this context. Being offended is not an argument in any way. However, I do sympathize with the idea that the rules should be the same for everyone. Otherwise, what's next? Users with 20K rep opening a topic about who else is barbecuing in February?

Comment: @Lucia Please use comment notifications when you reply. I do not "[insist] that no perspective besides one's own can be valid." Indeed I engage in a discussions on the subject to sharpen which viewpoints on a subject may be  valid and which  not so much. In my opinion there is a difference  between a "valid viewpoint" that I might not share, and just some opinion somebody voiced. Besides you use the word "respected"  and while I may accept this opinion, I am sorry but I just do not respect it as it runs counter fundamental principles important to me.

Comment: For what it is worth, I certainly think that the real world identity of a poster can and should be taken into account when responding (whether by comments, answers, or moderation actions) to a post. It's long established that the moderation team here mostly encourage users to post under real world identities. Remember, MathOverflow is not part of "the internet" --- it is part of the world of professional research mathematics.

Comment: The discussed question may be not great, but I wonder what should  make it less on-topic than e.g. the [question on where to buy premium white chalk](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26267/where-to-buy-premium-white-chalk-in-the-u-s-like-they-have-at-rims) which remained open for 5 years. In any case, I don't see a particular point in closing occasional borderline questions of people like Richard Stanley who have contributed a lot to this site -- if some people like them, why not just leave them open.

Comment: @ScottMorrison there may very well be a fundamental difference in our perception for a good community. In mine established members would strive to  follow the standards more closely than it is expected from new ones to set a good example and not the opposite. This applies here and  everywhere.

Comment: @StefanKohl: Adhering to the rules is sometimes the hard thing to do, especially in a borderline case. (Not saying that this is the case here, btw.) One doesn't like to risk offending an important individual, and more generally one wishes to be nice to one's peers (or betters). That's all commendable, but only so long as it doesn't interfere with proper enforcement of the basic rules of this site. I see some people engaging in mental contortions in order to argue that the topic *is* in line with the MO philosophy, but I wonder if they'd also be sticking their necks out for user498487.

Comment: @StefanKohl Because quality chalk is directly relevant to my professional life as a mathematician. And this *quod licet jovi* attitude is part of the reason I'm not as active on MathOverflow as on SciComp.

Comment: Honestly, I'm surprised there even is such a discussion -- some who's been around long enough to earn 20k reputation shouldn't be offended by a polite "Sorry, as currently written, this question is off-topic here. Presumably you're asking here rather than on physics.SE because you want to know about some specific mathematical background. Would you mind editing your question to make this explicit?" (Which, incidentally, is exactly what I would have written for a rep 1 user.)

Comment: @René: At least in my understanding, like in 'real life' also on MO there is a notable difference between a person of some standing who acts under their real name and an anonymous 'user498487'.

Comment: @StefanKohl: Certainly there's a difference, when the question is whether to give someone the benefit of the doubt or not. But in this case the rules are clearly violated, so there's no room for doubt. Whenever the rules point in a clear direction, they should be applied regardless of who is concerned in the matter. Or do you disagree about that?

Comment: @René: At the time of writing this, Richard Stanley's question has score +28. -- I am not convinced that this is in line with your assertion that "the rules are clearly violated" by his question, at least not unless you elaborate on why you think they would. Site rules are not set in stone, but always up to interpretation by the community.

Comment: @StefanKohl: Yes, but the mere fact that rules are subject to change over time doesn't mean that they aren't still rules. Like this one (from http://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic): "MathOverflow's primary goal is for users to ask and answer research level math questions, the sorts of questions you come across when you're writing or reading articles or graduate level books. [...]" I don't see why 30+ upvotes would invalidate this basic part of the MO mission statement. However, I will now withdraw from this discussion, as I don't think it'll result in any changes (unfortunately).

Comment: @StefanKohl As you may or may not be aware of, the question has reached the "hot network questions" list on Stack Exchange, which is displayed on *every* page on the entire network, incredibly boosting exposure and voting while usually being indicative of being of less interest from experts as documented e.g. [here on Physics Meta](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6303/the-secret-to-getting-a-massive-reputation-is), because a popular "HNQ" post is usually very low-level (the case at hand is no exception). Please don't confuse this with good reception from the community.

Answer (score 31):

It seems that the moderators' opinions are not unified on this question, so I will offer my view wearing my private citizen hat.

The question asks how various parameters of an apparent black hole collision were extracted from LIGO data.  If we made a Venn diagram that let us sort questions by subject, I think this question would fall squarely in the "applied math" bubble, together with substantial intersections with other fields.  I hold the position that applied math should be welcome at MathOverflow, with the proviso that questions should be written in a language resembling that of mathematicians.

If someone approached me on the street and asked me this question, I would reply something like, "the recorded waveform was probably matched to numerical simulation data, and bounds on errors were derived from known noise characteristics", but I would be unable to elaborate on any details.  I think this question is an opportunity for more mathematically informative answers to be given by people who are familiar with numerical GR and the LIGO project in particular.  For example, I have heard from practitioners that there have been substantial advances in numerical GR in the 21st century that draw on nontrivial theoretical mathematics, and I would be interested to know in more detail what those advances are and to what extent they have helped with the extraction of the relevant figures.

Finally, I think the observation of gravitational waves is an incredibly important scientific discovery, and this question in particular is an on-topic forum for illuminating intersections with research mathematics.

Comment: It does not really ask what you say it asks. Would it be as specific as you describe it, it would already be better;

Comment: @quid Richard Stanley provided some parameters, and asked how the conclusions were reached.  I see no substantial difference between his question and my description.

Comment: Well, there is a difference nevertheless. The question as it stands asks, very succinctly, how certain "*conclusions*" were reached. No word about parameters, might I add. It also doesn't specify that the answer should be about the applied mathematics side of the matter, so it seems just as likely that the asker is interested in the physics, not the maths. Indeed, given the stipulation "assuming no deep knowledge of GR", and given that the sole tag is general-relativity, I'd even say that that is more likely.

Comment: @René I would fully support an edit to the question that emphasized more the applied mathematics aspects, so as to keep the discussion on-topic for this site. (Something like this suggestion also came up in private discussion between moderators.) Is that an edit you'd feel comfortable performing?

Comment: Dear Todd: I'm afraid I wouldn't, because I don't want to interfere with the intent of the question. Also, I feel we should be discussing the merits of the question in the form in which it was asked, not in the form that might be given to it.

Comment: @René I would prefer to give Richard Stanley the benefit of the doubt here, and assume that the word "conclusions" does not exist in a context-free vacuum, but instead refers specifically to the information given in the immediately preceding sentences of the question, e.g., the numerical parameters like the masses of the black holes. Similarly, long-time users of this site can be expected to know the rules, and we can safely assume that they are not asking for popular-science or introductory physics tutorials.

Comment: @René That's fine. But whether an edit should be performed to a controversial question is something that regularly comes up in meta discussions, and I think it's fine to discuss it in this case.

Comment: The difference in my mind is where the explication of the chain of reasoning/observations leading to the conclusion mentioned in the question should start. The question is unclear in that regard. For example, the question: "Given some recorded waveform, how can we conclude [this] caused it rather than something else?" is different from the question "How can we record data that allows to conclude [this] happened?" You seem to make a case for the former, but the  answer by user1504 who also defends the questions addresses the latter broader question.

Comment: For instance "These gravitational waves interact with the laser interferometer detectors by expanding and contracting their axes. You can measure the phase difference in the recombined lasers. Take data more or less continuously and get lucky, and you'll sometimes sample waveforms we think are particular to binary black hole mergers, given what we know about the evolution of star populations." This does not look like a discussion of applied mathematics to me, rather this looks like a moderately sophisticated popular-science description of a physics experiment.

Comment: In that sense, yes, indeed the question does not live in  a context free vacuum. The way it is interpreted by those that answer it is already there. And what I see seems like  popular-science physics not 21st century numerical GR.

Comment: "the recorded waveform was probably matched to numerical simulation data, and bounds on errors were derived from known noise characteristics"  I find this the perfect answer to the OP. But I would not think that it would be an appropriate answer on MO. I think similar about the original question: It's a good question to start a conversation but not for MO.

Comment: @S.Carnahan: As far as I can see, Richard Stanley was asking a physics question, pure and simple. I'm not going along with your argument that since R.S. must be aware of the rules, he can't be wilfully breaking them. By that logic, established users can *never* be in the wrong, which is precisely the kind of thinking some of us here are criticizing.

Comment: "Finally, I think the observation of gravitational waves is an incredibly important scientific discovery, and this question in particular is an on-topic forum for illuminating intersections with research mathematics".... Do we need a special tag for things of this nature (although they are not frequent)?

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju no this would be a meta-tag.

Comment: How long is the benefit of the doubt maintained? I suppose long-time users of this site can be expected to know that questions perceived as unclear are to be clarified via an edit. Or, is this incorrect?

Comment: @quid I don't see any need for editing the question.  However, I do see a need for less legalistic gate-keeping of topics on MathOverflow.  Your supposition is quite loaded with an ambiguous passive voice, so I would call it "poorly defined and unnecessarily aggressive" rather than "incorrect".

Comment: I find it in bad taste to focus on linguistic details in an asymmetric situation. I write in your (I think) not in my native language. The passive voice was used to stress that it could be done by somebody else, as opposed to insisting OP needs to do it themselves. In my perception this indirection is actually more polite. But the actual point of the comment was to make you maybe realize that your similar formulation is just counterfactual in general. There are numerous long-term users simply oblivious to rules, without ill will or it being a problem IMO..But let us not pretend otherwise.

Comment: Actually you insisting on it being otherwise makes the situation more complicated, as it gives a gravity to the situation that is just not there. You block the easy out of compromise, and I really do not get why.

Comment: @quid Indirection causes ambiguity by removing the intended subject, and often has passive-aggressive connotations.  Should Richard Stanley be the one who has to edit if quid is the one who perceives the question as unclear?  As long as we're are in an asymmetric situation, I would recommend against using the word "rules" in this context (yes, I know I started it) and replacing it with something like "rough guidelines" or "community norms" that conveys more flexibility.  That said, I don't know of any long-term users who interact with the site in a particularly norm-violating way.

Comment: By "giving the benefit of doubt", I mean choosing good interpretations out of the set of reasonable ones and using those.  Based on various reactions, it seems that contrary to my initial expectation, people find that both your interpretation and my interpretation of the question are reasonable.  It happens that my interpretation is one that leads to good answers.  user1504's first answer before the later improvements was already mathematically substantial, and the paragraph you selectively quoted was physical context but not the core of the content.

Comment: I have no idea what the core of the content was, because as a non-physicist I couldn't make heads or tails out of the entire answer.

Comment: "Should Richard Stanley be the one who has to edit if quid is the one who perceives the question as unclear?" With the level of sensitiveness you apply, and given the context, I'd say one could consider your formulation as a slight. But beyond this, while I would not say "has to" and it is not necessarily an edit, the simple answer is yes usually it would be the nice and professional thing to do for an author to be responsive to  reasonable inquiries and remarks on their posts. (Of course there can always be circumstances that prevent this in a specific case.)

Comment: You say "choosing good interpretations out of the set of reasonable ones and using those." This is fine (though the plural is noteworthy and telling). But what is wrong with making those *interpretations* explicit and removing ambiguity? Really, this is all that is asked for. Or, to make the subject explicit: this is all I ask for (and I think I am not alone).

Comment: Sorry to come back, but I meant to reply to some specific points raised, yet was pressed when I initially replied: *On not following guidelines.* There is a long established guideline to use at least one top-level tag if at all possible. This is frequently not done,  also by long-term users. This is small thing for sure, but it *is* an example of long-term users not following guidelines, presumably for rather trivial reasons of not knowing about them or not recalling to apply them.  You might reply this does not qualify as "particularly norm-violating way" to which I would however reply

Comment: a question "asking for popular-science or introductory physics tutorials" (in the given context) would not be either. There is a history of users, including long-term users, asking something only vaguely related to the topic of the site, and this is not a big deal IMO. // (Added later) I removed the second half of the original comment, as it is tangential. Let me also add that on second reading I found your last comment more consensus oriented than I read it originally. (I still do not agree with your assessment of the original answer, but this is tangential too.) Maybe we can leave it there.

Answer (score 20):

My view is that what should count is the (academic/scientific interest) times (the amount of mathematics involved). So if the academic interest is huge and the mathematical component is modest we should go for it. (Perhaps even actively try to ask about mathematics angles of super major developments in other sciences.) In other words if something huge happens far away in other sciences we should still try to intercept its  waves on MO

Comment: To make this explicit is a very good idea in my view. It seems to me it is what happened in practice not rarely anyway. To be open about it will resolve most of the problems I have with this type of question. In fact, as said, I found the specific question a positive example in this regard.

Answer (score 18):

I find it difficult to understand many of the comments and concerns that this question seems to have raised.  The site has a fairly simple and well established procedure for closing/keeping open questions:  five votes to close, five to reopen, five more to close and so on.  In situations where reasonable people can disagree, this seems a perfectly fine way to resolve the disagreement -- one may be unhappy with the community decision, but one can still accept it with good grace (as I will if the question under discussion is closed again).

A similar question (in terms of suitability for the site, not to me in terms of interest) came up not so long back [Optical methods for number theory?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/172109/optical-methods-for-number-theory) where I found myself on the other side.  I thought this was not suitable for the site, and there I felt that the OP had not made quality contributions to justify the benefit of doubt (again people will disagree with this, but I am merely expressing my view of the question -- the OP in that case continued to ask poorly thought out questions afterwards).   In that case, it was argued in Meta that the question could be salvaged and reopened, which is what happened. I found (and still find) little to complain of in that situation.

I learnt at least one interesting tidbit from the comments above: Quod licet Iovi, non licet bovi.  The gods may do what cattle may not.  The commenter of course disagreed entirely with this sentiment, but comparison with the above question suggests to me that sometimes on MO the situation may be exactly the other way around -- conscious of potential injustices, people are happy to stand up for those who are not well established.  That seems to me like a fine principle and I applaud it, but perhaps the "gods" can also be allowed the same privileges as the "cattle"?

Comment: What I find puzzling is precisely that there's no talk of salvaging the question (i.e., editing to make clear it's about the mathematical background) -- it's as if the post of a high rep user/eminent scientist (not clear what's the driving force here) is sacrosanct and may not be touched. This is contrary to what would happen to an unknown user (as in the question you refer to) and to the detriment of the site.

Comment: It's true, almost no single question will be much of a problem; certainly the one in question is not. When there is a discussion and when there is just voting, is somewhat hard to predict. In this case a reason for me to enter a discussion was the first comment after closure: "This strikes me as no more off topic than some random exercise in the theory of moduli stacks." This is very strange thing to say. On the last phrase, first, I think in practice there is a bit of privilege in fact, but second. as S. Carnahan said: " long-time users of this site can be expected to know the rules[...]"

Comment: Separately, then such discussions have a certain dynamic. I for one vehemently do not see this site as some in-club, and therefore speak against such tendencies when they arise. Some things said are in my opinion just appalling. (Those that say them are of course entitled to their opinion, and for some it is no news they have them and still we get along.) It starts to be off-topic, but what I see and read on this site over the years severely degraded my perception of the actual math-community. (To be clear, I am in every reasonable sense part of it. This is not an outsider remark.)

Answer (score 17):

The specific question asked seems like asking for a popular-science explication of a result in physics (written for mathematicians).
It seems like a private idle curiosity, as contrasted with a problem encountered as a mathematician.

Would the question be written differently and say, focus on a specific aspect the situation might be different. As it is I think it is also too broad.

Without claiming any expertise on the subject, I am still pretty sure that there are numerous aspects to "how these conclusions were reached" presumably touching on several distinct areas of applied mathematics.

The question that may have been intended to ask is one were a lot of the difficulty is abstracted away already, and the focus is on the inverse problem of determining/estimating the parameters of the objects assuming one has knowledge on the waves. If this is the case, then it should be made explicit.

Finally, I will remark that at least two of the users that had voted to close have a mathematical physics background.